# C++ Class instance array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, g++, valgrind

I have a class A as follows:

```
class A
{
public:    
    A()
    {        
        printf("A constructed\n");        
    }
    ~A();
    //no other constructors/assignment operators    
}
```

I have the following elsewhere

```
A * _a;
```

I initalize it with:

```
int count = ...
...
_a = new A[count];
```

and I access it with

```
int key = ....
...
A *a_inst = &(_a[key]);
....
```

It runs normally, and the printf in the constructor is executed, and all the fields in A are fine.

I ran Valgrind with the following args:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes -v ./A_app
```

and Valgrind keeps yelling about

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

and then the stack trace to the accessors statements.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? **Specifically if what Valgrind says is true, why is the constructor executed?**

Comment: Specifically which line is flagged by valgrind, and which line does it say is the origin of the uninitialized value?

Comment: Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation. And it points at the line that new'ed the array.

Comment: And which line was flagged as depending on the uninitialized value?

Comment: The line number for the actual error is when I use a class member of the object after using the accessor to get the object

Comment: Then you must not be properly initializing that class member in your constructor.  You did not post that part of your code.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Weird though. Thought non-pointer ints/bools in a class should be auto-set to 0.

Comment: If you declare a constructor then it will only initialize what your constructor initializes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can mean that `key` or `count` contains an uninitialized value.  Even if you do initialize it in the declaration, e.g. `int key = foo + bar;`, it could be that either `foo` or `bar` is uninitialized, and valgrind carries this over to `key`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. While I'm checking through the code, is there a valgrind option that shows those details?

Comment: Since you are using --track-origins=yes it should tell you the origin of the uninitialized value in the next message.

Comment: Ah this is interesting. The line number for the actual error is when I use a class member of the object after using the accessor to get the object.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Try setting `A *a = 0;`

Running your code in an a simplified scenario does not produce any warnings from Valgrind. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A()   
        {     
            std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        }     
};

int main()
{
    A *a; 
    int count = 10; 
    a = new A[count];

    int key = 1;
    A *inst = &(a[key]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
$ g++ -g main.cc -o main
```

and run with:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes ./main
```

So, I think more information is needed. You are likely doing something between defining _a and actually allocating memory on the heap. Might I simply suggest that you merge the definition and allocation into one line?

```
    int count = 10; 
    A *a = new A[count];
```

Comment: You need --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes -v

Comment: Still no warnings on my system :)

Comment: Hmm weird... but the stuff I have above is the correct initialization right?

Comment: Looks good to me. I think the simple way to shut up Valgrind is to allocate right away. Is there a reason why you are deferring allocation?

Comment: Yea it's a class member. Can't allocate directly.

Comment: I can only blindly guess at this point, but perhaps initialising to 0 will either reveal the problem or fix it: A *a = 0;